# Putting a condition on window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = (e) ->
  e = e or window.event
  e.preventDefault = true
  e.cancelBubble = true
  e.returnValue = "You are not done yet with your Pleading Assembly."
  # if leave this page is click then
  #  notify
  return
```

And I don't know what line of code triggered the button "Leave this Page".

Button "Leave this page" exist even I omit this

```
e.preventDefault = true
e.cancelBubble = true
```

What I want to do is put a condition that if I click "Leave this page" Button, something will happen (in my part, I will notify a user)

But unfortunately, I have no idea at all what should I do.

Comment: check what is the value for that button using `e.target.getText()`

Comment: Is there a `coffeescript -> javascript` compilation step that is possibly not taking affect?  Check your compiler.  Also, if you're using chrome, I know that it caches very aggressively.  You might want to turn on the cache disable checkbox in chrome dev tools.  And clear your cache as well.

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing you can do after "Leave this page" (because the user has, well... left the page). It's a security thing (to make it so users cannot be prevented from leaving)

Comment: due to abuse over the years there isn't a lot you can do with onbeforeunload. Browsers like firefox won't even display your custom text. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload

Comment: Is there no way to put a condition after I clicked "Leave this page" Button?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava, how I use it? Like this? `console.log e.target.getText()`

Comment: nope like `console.log(e.target.getText())`